# Nested loop causing strange results

Tags: c++

I'm working on a problem in order to find prime numbers between 2 and 100.  My idea was to:

`1: Create a list of odd numbers up to 100`

`2: Use a nested loop to try and divide each number in the list`

`3: If the number is divisible, mark as -1 in the list (not a prime)`

`4: Print out all numbers that are not equal to -1`

I'm aware that there are more efficient ways to find these primes, but I don't care right now.
When I get to `i == 4` in the nested loop it seems to be assigned to -1, where I'm expecting the value to be the next odd number (9).  I do not understand why this is happening.  This is the code I have written:

```
#ifndef EX10
#define EX10
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Ex10
{
public:
    void Go()
    {
        vector<int> vecNums;
        vecNums.push_back(2);

        // Get all our test numbers.
        for(int i = 3; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            if(i % 2 == 1)
            {
                vecNums.push_back(i);
            }
        }

        cout << "Numbers filled" << endl;

        // Loop through dividing numbers
        for(int i = 0; i < vecNums.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(i == 4)
            {
                cout << "i " << vecNums[i] << endl; // Why is this -1?
            }
            for(int j = i+1; j < vecNums.size(); ++j)
            {
                if(vecNums[j] % vecNums[i] == 0 && vecNums[j] != -1)
                {
                    //cout << "i " << vecNums[i] << endl;
                    //cout << "j " << vecNums[j] << endl;
                    //not a prime
                    vecNums[j] = -1;
                }
            }
        }

        cout << "Primes found" << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < vecNums.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(vecNums[i] != -1)
            {
                cout << vecNums[i] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I would change the first for loop to `for(int i=3;i<100;i+=2) {/*do stuff*/}` to avoid the call to `if`.

Comment: Hold up.  You have `if (vecNums[i] == 4) cout << vecNums[i];`.  This will always be 4, if it says anything.  Your error is elsewhere.

Comment: @Proxy Sorry, was a typo.  I have now made the amendment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 9 is not prime.  So it gets set to -1 the first time through in your loop, like it's supposed to.

`if(vecNums[j] % vecNums[i] == 0 && vecNums[j] != -1)`
at the first go through your outer loop gets to the fourth iteration of your inner loop
`if(vecNums[4] % vecNums[1] == 0 && vecNums[4] != -1)`
which evaluates to
`if(9 % 3 == 0 && 9 != -1)`

However, you should be careful because once you get -1 in your list, your going to being doing modulo -1.  That's going to give you wonky results.  You need to not run the inner loop if vecNums[i] == -1

Comment: I should have looking to see if vecNum[i] != -1, rather than vecNum[j].  Debugging is so much easier in Visual Studios!

Answer (score 0):

That got changed to `-1` when `i == 2` and `j == 4`.

Comment: @Michael: I believe that this is an answer.  The OP is confused why `vecNums[i] == -1` when `i == 4`, and this is why.

Comment: Noted..comment deleted